# Add support for keyboard shortcuts in Discussions

Tags: feature-request, status-review, discussions-space, keyboard-shortcuts

I often use keyboard shortcuts to navigate lists of posts or have quick access to actions like voting.

However, there is currently no support for keyboard shortcuts in Discussions. It is *jarring* moving from a tab which has a list of questions, to a tab that has a list of discussions and needing to reach for the mouse.

Enable the use of keyboard shortcuts to help with accessibility and to keep the interaction with the site uniform across different pages.